# How to drag & drop JTable row that includes an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, imageicon

I have a `JTable` with several columns including a column of `ImageIcon`s.  My other `JTable`s that do not have `ImageIcon`s work fine with my drag & drop code. However when an `ImageIcon` is in the row, I get a serialization error.

```
    // Drag and drop
    setDragEnabled(true);
    setDropMode(INSERT_ROWS);
    class TableRowTransferHandler extends TransferHandler
    {
        private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor =
                new ActivationDataFlavor(Object[].class,
                        DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType);

        private JTable tbl = null;

        public TableRowTransferHandler(JTable tbl)
        {
            this.tbl = tbl;
        }

        @Override
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
        {
            // Store the source selected rows.
            JTable tableSource = (JTable)c;
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tableSource.
                    getModel();

            ArrayList<Object> listSourceRows = new ArrayList<>();

            int selectedRowCount      = ((JTable)c).getSelectedRowCount();
            int[] selectedRowsIndexes = ((JTable)c).getSelectedRows();

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
            {
                int modelRowIdx = tableSource.convertRowIndexToModel(
                        selectedRowsIndexes[i]);
                listSourceRows.add(model.getDataVector().elementAt(
                        modelRowIdx));
            }

            return(new DataHandler(listSourceRows.toArray(),
                    localObjectFlavor.getMimeType()));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport info)
        {
            return (tbl.getDragEnabled()       &&
                    info.getComponent() == tbl &&
                    info.isDrop()              &&
                    info.isDataFlavorSupported(localObjectFlavor));
        }

        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
        {
            return TransferHandler.MOVE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport info)
        {
            // Put the stored rows into the destination table.
            JTable tableDestination = (JTable) info.getComponent();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tableDestination.
                    getModel();
            JTable.DropLocation dropLoc = (JTable.DropLocation)info.
                    getDropLocation();

            int rowDropIndex = dropLoc.getRow();
            int max = getRowCount();

            if (rowDropIndex < 0 || rowDropIndex > max)
            {
                rowDropIndex = max;
            }

            try
            {
                // Insert the stored rows into the destination table.
                Object[] values = (Object[])info.getTransferable().
                        getTransferData(localObjectFlavor);

                // LIFO
                for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Object value = values[i];
                    model.insertRow(rowDropIndex, (Vector)value);
                }

                return(true);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void exportDone(JComponent src,
                                  Transferable t,
                                  int action)
        {
            // Remove the selected rows from the source table.
            JTable tableSource = (JTable)src;
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tableSource.
                    getModel();

            int selectedRowCount    = tableSource.getSelectedRowCount();
            int[] selectedViewRows  = tableSource.getSelectedRows();
            int[] selectedModelRows = new int[tableSource.
                    getSelectedRowCount()];

            // Convert from view to model
            for(int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
            {
                selectedModelRows[i] = convertRowIndexToModel(
                        selectedViewRows[i]);
            }

            Arrays.sort(selectedModelRows);

            // Remove rows from the bottom up so the indexes don't change)
            for (int i = selectedRowCount - 1; 0 <= i ; i--)
            {
                model.removeRow(selectedModelRows[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    setTransferHandler(new TableRowTransferHandler(this));
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: 

javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableHeaderUI
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(JComponent.java:5534)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.writeObject(EventListenerList.java:258)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
    at javax.swing.JTable.writeObject(JTable.java:5845)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.writeObject(ImageIcon.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:481)
    at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1073)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferData(TransferableProxy.java:83)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferData(DropTargetContext.java:376)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.GUIUtils.GUIUtilWBTable$1TableRowTransferHandler.importData(GUIUtilWBTable.java:852)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1536)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:450)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1274)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:544)
    at sun.awt.X11.XDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(XDropTargetContextPeer.java:184)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:858)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:782)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4727)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4566)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4417)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.runMain(Main.java:88)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.access$000(Main.java:17)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main$1.run(Main.java:27)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTableUI.java:1728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1660)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:790)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.validateView(JViewport.java:485)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.scrollRectToVisible(JViewport.java:396)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.scrollRectToVisible(JComponent.java:3107)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionConsoleManager.MCMMasterHeadersTablePanel$9.valueChanged(MCMMasterHeadersTablePanel.java:1478)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:576)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JTable.restoreSortingSelection(JTable.java:4210)
    at javax.swing.JTable.access$500(JTable.java:221)
    at javax.swing.JTable$SortManager.restoreSelection(JTable.java:4023)
    at javax.swing.JTable$SortManager.processChange(JTable.java:3997)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4129)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4395)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:261)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:464)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.GUIUtils.GUIUtilWBTable$1TableRowTransferHandler.exportDone(GUIUtilWBTable.java:899)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DragHandler.dragDropEnd(TransferHandler.java:1642)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext.dragDropEnd(DragSourceContext.java:435)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDragSourceContextPeer$EventDispatcher.run(SunDragSourceContextPeer.java:487)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.runMain(Main.java:88)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.access$000(Main.java:17)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main$1.run(Main.java:27)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTableUI.java:1728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1660)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:790)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:691)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1676)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.runMain(Main.java:88)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.access$000(Main.java:17)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main$1.run(Main.java:27)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel$Handler.repaintIfBackgroundsDiffer(SynthLookAndFeel.java:965)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel$Handler.propertyChange(SynthLookAndFeel.java:926)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.firePropertyChange(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1426)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.setGlobalFocusOwner(KeyboardFocusManager.java:572)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:590)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4742)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.SentEvent.dispatch(SentEvent.java:70)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager$DefaultKeyboardFocusManagerSentEvent.dispatch(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:216)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.sendMessage(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:243)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:687)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4742)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(SequencedEvent.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.runMain(Main.java:88)
    at gov.wreckingball.wbs.MissionPlannerConsole.Main.access$000(Main.java:17)
    at
```

How do I change my code to drag and drop rows that have `ImageIcon`s?

Comment: add the exception that you are getting.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: .. when can we expect to see the MCVE/SSCCE?

Comment: As I am multitasking on several projects, I may not get to it until early next week.

Comment: Tip: Add @Grinish (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `ActivationDataFlavor` is overloaded.  The method's parameters should be

```
    private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor =
        new ActivationDataFlavor(Object[].class,
            DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, 
                "Array of Objects");
```